# How do you include/exclude a certain type of files under Subversion?

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm getting confused with the include/exclude jargon, and my actual SVN client doesn't seem to have (or I've been unable to find it easily) a simple option to add or remove a certain type of files for version control.

Let's say for example I've added the entire Visual Studio folder, with its solutions, projects, debug files, etc., but I only want to version the actual source files. What would be the simplest way to do that?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You're probably safest excluding particular filetypes, rather than picking those you want to include, as you could then add a new type and not realize it wasn't versioned.

On a per-directory basis, you can edit the [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) property.

Run

```
svn propedit svn:ignore .
```

for each relevant directory to bring up an editor with a list of patterns to ignore.

Then put a pattern on each line corresponding to the filetype you'd like to ignore:

```
*.user
*.exe
*.dll
```

and what have you.

Alternatively, as has been suggested, you can add those patterns to the `global-ignores` property in your ~/.subversion/config file (or `"%APPDATA%\Subversion\config"` on Windows - see [Configuration Area Layout in the red bean book for more information](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07.html#svn-ch-7-sect-1.1)). In that case, separate the patterns with spaces. Here's mine. `#` at the beginning of the line introduces a comment. I've ignored Ankh .Load files and all *.resharper.user files:

```
### Set global-ignores to a set of whitespace-delimited globs
### which Subversion will ignore in its 'status' output, and
### while importing or adding files and directories.
# global-ignores = *.o *.lo *.la #*# .*.rej *.rej .*~ *~ .#* .DS_Store
global-ignores = Ankh.Load *.resharper.user
```

Comment: To add to TortoiseSVN's global ignore settings, right click your project folder, TortoiseSVN... Settings... General... and in the Subversion area, you can edit the "Global ignore pattern".

Comment: Is it possible to add ignore per project? As in git. In git you put ignore file in project root and that takes precedence over global ignore.

Answer (score 5):

This can be achieved using the [svn:ignore](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s02.html#svn-ch-7-sect-2.3.3) property, or the global-ignores property in your `~/.subversion/config` file. (Scroll to the top of that first link to see instructions on editing properties.)

By using `svn propset` or `svn propedit` on a directory, you will be able to make Subversion ignore all files matching that pattern within the specific directory. If you change global-ignores in `~/.subversion/config`'s `[miscellany]` section, however, Subversion will ignore such files no matter where they are located.

Answer (score 2):

See blog post *[svn:ignore](http://athenageek.wordpress.com/2008/04/16/svnignore/)*.

I know using TortoiseSVN that I can click on a root folder where I have something checked out and can add arbitrary properties by selecting the "Properties" menu item. In this case you would just specify file patterns to exclude.

The blog post for command line stuff, but I'm sure it will work fine with whatever client you're using.

Answer (score 1):

At the lowest level, SVN allows you to ignore certain files or patterns with [svn:ignore](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/662.cfm) attribute. VS add-ins for SVN such as [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/) will automatically ignore those files on your behalf. If you're using [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), you can right-click files and folders in Explorer and choose *Add to Ignore List*.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `svn:ignore` property, you can use wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, when using TortoiseSVN, you can select "Commit..." and then right click on a file and move to changelist "ignore-on-commit".

Answer (score 0):

If you use Eclipse (I use Spring Tool Suite):

```
Preferences > Team > Ignored Resources
```

click on `Add Pattern`, write **.DS_Store** (or whatever) and Save.
This acts globally in your workspace.