# What is the appropriate pattern to ignore *.config except for packages.config in svn?

Tags: svn, svnignore

I'd like to ignore all files with a specific extension (e.g. *.config) since they are generated, except for files named "packages.config", which is static. In essence, a developer should not accidentally checkin in something like app.config, bob.config, web.config or any other file with the extension of ".config"

What is the appropiate pattern for svn:ignore?

**What I tried**

If I set the svn:ignore to

```
*.exe
*.dll
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
[Rr]elease
[Dd]ebug
*.config
```

then all files are ignored, including packages.config. This is expected. So then I wanted to verify I can exclude all configuration files with packages in the filename.

```
*.exe
*.dll
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
[Rr]elease
[Dd]ebug
packages.config
```

which does the trick.

However, I was unable to get the inverse of that pattern. I searched the internet for examples and found mention using ["^"](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=462&dsMessageId=669947) and another using ["!"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137761/using-svnignore-to-ignore-everything-but-certain-files).

I tried

```
*.exe
*.dll
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
[Rr]elease
[Dd]ebug
!packages.config
```

which didn't have the desired effect. At this point I realize that I clearly don't understand how to achieve this. So I tried adding `!packages.config` and then `*.config`.

```
*.exe
*.dll
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
[Rr]elease
[Dd]ebug
!packages.config
*.config
```

and `*.config` and then `!packages.config`

```
*.exe
*.dll
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
[Rr]elease
[Dd]ebug
*.config
!packages.config
```

and adding `^packages.config`

```
*.exe
*.dll
[Bb]in
[Oo]bj
[Rr]elease
[Dd]ebug
^packages.config
```

that didn't work.

**Sources**

Many of the websites I visited focused on how to exclude files.

- [Ignoring Unversioned Items](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html)
- [How do you include/exclude a certain type of files under Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122313/how-do-you-include-exclude-a-certain-type-of-files-under-subversion)
- [Re: inverse of svn:ignore property](http://subversion.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=462&dsMessageId=669947)
- [Shell Command Language](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html) (tortoise svn linked to this page to understand pattern matching)
- [Using svn:ignore to ignore everything but certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137761/using-svnignore-to-ignore-everything-but-certain-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word: You can't...

However, if you already have `packages.config`in your repository, then it won't be *ignored* even if svn ignore is set to `*.config`. You can't ignore stuff already in the repository.

However, from what you want, it sounds like you can use my [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) for finer control over your situation. My hook takes a list of rules specified in a control file. For file rules, the last rule that matches the file's name is the access they're granted. In your situation, you would have two rules:

```
[FILE Configuration files must be named "packages.config"]
file = **/*.config
access = no-add
users = @ALL

[FILE Configuration files must be named "packages.config"]
file = **/packages.config
access = read-write
users = @ALL
```

If someone tried to add `bob.config`, to the repository, my first rule is in effect. `bob.config` matches `*.config`, and that rule says you can't add any files that end in `.config`.

However, if someone tries to add `packages.config` to the repository, it will work because although `packages.config` matches the first rule and the first rule prohibits it, `packages.config` also matches the second rule which allows it. The second rule wins over the first rule.

As a bonus, my pre-commit hook will prohibit adding in `bob.config` even if the user tried to ignore the ignore (which users are free to do).